# Get key value from xml string 2 dimensional

Tags: php, xml

I want to read some values from a string. The string is in xml format now.
How do I get the Artist from this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<song>
<filename>c699da47ed08bd80927ae148c1b5b0fd.mp3</filename>
<title>Interlude (Imam Siraj)</title>
<artist>Native Deen</artist>
<album>Not Afraid To Stand Alone</album>
<year>2007</year>
<genre>R&B</genre>
<duration>0:01:20 (approx)</duration>
</song>
```

I have tried using simplexml but cannot figure out how to get the elements within.

$xml = simplexml_load_string($strXML);
$strArtist = ???

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual [simplexml-load-string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

`$strArtist  = $xml->artist`

Comment: Yes, Thank, you. I have been trying to call objects like that and even tried the loadfile function as well incase the xml string was somehow not formatted right. It still does not work. print_r($xml) does not even work. I am beginning to think simple xml isn't even installed on my mac osx workstaion yet it throws no error.